# Does there exist homeomorphism without fixed points?

Tags: geometric-topology

Does there exist a homeomorphism of the unit disk with two holes $$\left\{(x,y):x^2+y^2 \le 1\right\} \setminus \left (\left \{(x,y):\left(x+ \frac 1 2 \right)^2+y^2 < \frac 1 {10} \right \} \bigcup \left \{(x,y):\left(x-\frac 1 2 \right)^2+y^2 < \frac 1 {10}\right\}\right)$$ on itself without any fixed point?

Comment: Try finding a homeomorphism to a simpler space, and solve the problem there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Your space is homeomorphic to the standard unit sphere $S^2\subseteq\mathbb R^3$ with three open disks removed. These disks can be chosen so that the rotation of $\mathbb R^3$ by $\frac{2\pi}3$ around some axis cyclically permutes them. This rotation, however, has two fixed points, where the axis of rotation intersects $S^2$. Compose it with a reflection across the plane perpendicular to your axis and you are done. (The disks can be chosen so that this reflection preserves them.)

Comment: Is it true that any *orientation preserving* homeomorphism does have a fixedpoint? I think so

Comment: @ronno: But if said fixed point is in the holes, then it's not a fixed point of the homeomorphism of the space of interest.

Comment: Incidentally, fixed point free orientation preserving examples do not exist. Just use the Lefschetz number.